# How to suppress `Wrote /home/user/.emacs.d/recentf` message in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, advice, message, recentf, nadvice

In the minibuffer I keep seeing:

```
Wrote /home/user/.emacs.d/recentf
```

Would it be possible to suppress this message? (Only for file name `recentf`  file)

---

my minimal.el:

```
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 50)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 50)
(setq recentf-exclude '("^/var/folders\\.*"
                        "[/\\]\\.elpa/"
                        "COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'"
                        "\\TODO_archive\\'"
                        ))
(run-at-time nil (* 5 60) 'recentf-save-list)
(add-hook 'delete-terminal-functions (lambda (terminal) (recentf-save-list)))
(recentf-load-list)
(setq recentf-save-file (recentf-expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/.recentf"))
(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 10)
(recentf-mode 1)
```

Comment: Maybe advise the recentf function that shows that message, let-binding `inhibit-message` around the function body?

Comment: @Drew How can I implement your advice?

Comment: I wrote you an answer that should do what you want.

Comment: @Drew Thank your sir,

Comment: You're welcome. The code is simple, and it might serve as a more general example, for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```lisp
(defun no-msg (function)
  "Prevent FUNCTION from showing `Wrote <FILE>' messages.
\(The messages are still logged to `*Messages*'.)"
  (let ((inhibit-message  t))
    (funcall function)))

(advice-add 'recentf-save-list :around 'no-msg)
```

To see the messages again, use `(advice-remove 'recentf-save-list 'no-msg)`.

Comment: I am not sure is it related but can similiear approach done for `Reverting buffer ‘config.yaml’.`  for specific file names? If not I can ask new question