# How to suppress `Type ‘C-c C-l’ to display results of compilation.` after compiling LaTeX file

Tags: latex

I am using following solution (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/65076/18414) to compile a `LaTeX` file:

> ```
> (defun my-run-latex ()
>   "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
>   (interactive)
>   (let* ((TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
>      (TeX-clean-confirm t)
>      (TeX-save-query nil)
>      (master (TeX-master-file))
>      (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master))))
>     (TeX-save-document master)
>     (when (and (processp process)
>            (eq (process-status process) 'run))
>       (delete-process process))
>     (TeX-command-master)))
> ```

---

After each time when I run `my-run-latex` function I keep seeing the following message in the minibuffer: `Type ‘C-c C-l’ to display results of compilation.`

Would it be possible to suppress this message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress \`Wrote /home/user/.emacs.d/recentf\` message in minibuffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/how-to-suppress-wrote-home-user-emacs-d-recentf-message-in-minibuffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable display of all `message`s:

```lisp
(defun my-run-latex ()
  "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((inhibit-message t)
         (TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
         (TeX-clean-confirm t)
         (TeX-save-query nil)
         (master (TeX-master-file))
         (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master))))
    (TeX-save-document master)
    (when (and (processp process)
               (eq (process-status process) 'run))
      (delete-process process))
    (TeX-command-master)))
```

Of course, you can set `inhibit-message` only on certain calls if you wanted to keep the message output of other calls.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. When I first run `my-run-latex` ; `Master file:` selection line shows up in the minibuffer. When I enter, it does not show up again and compiles right away. Is this a normal behavior?